# Python ldap3 Datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap3

I'm sending dates to LDAP via Python2/ldap3:

**Egress to LDAP (389DS):** *20190731000000Z*

However, when read from LDAP via Python3/ldap3:

**Ingress from LDAP (389DS):** *2019-07-31 00:00:00+00:00*

In LDAP the *EQUALITY* is *generalizedTimeMatch*.

What could be causing the discrepancy?

Comment: What discrepancy? The different format?

Comment: @khelwood Yes. When I do a diff, it doesn’t recognize as the same within python.

Comment: isn't the date stored as timestamp and then converted back to datetime object when withdrawn?

Comment: Within Python -- should I convert the ingress from LDAP to timestamp for the diff?